# handshake_failure in Jmeter4

Tags: java, https, jmeter

Tried many ways, still got `handshake_failure` in JMeter.

1. Get cer file from Chrome with different type cer and p7b(used OpenSSL to read out 4 parts certificate and save in 4 pem files)
2. Import in Keystore
3. Set SSL manager in Jmeter

error still show `handshake_failure`

Answer (score 0):

If you run your JMeter test in command-line non-GUI mode the SSL Manager will not work, you will need to set  `javax.net.ssl.keyStore` and `javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword` [system properties](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#configuring_jmeter), see [How to Set Your JMeter Load Test to Use Client Side Certificates](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-set-your-jmeter-load-test-use-client-side-certificates) article for more information.

Also "from Chrome" you're getting **server certificate**, for two-way SSL handshake you need to get the **client certificate**.

If this doesn't help, handshake failure may have different causes, for example:

1. Incorrect certificate, i.e. you're sending certificates in wrong order
2. You're using incompatible SSL version, check `https.default.protocol` property
3. You're using incompatible SSL protocol, check`https.socket.protocols` property
4. You're using incompatible [SSL Cipher Suite](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/SunProviders.html), check your Java version against **Default Enabled Cipher Suites** table

You can enable SSL debugging by adding the next line to *system.properties* file:

```
javax.net.debug=ssl
```

and compare the handshake with the [OpenSSL tool output](https://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/debugging-ssl-communications-from-unix-shell-prompt.html)